# Not getting the stored procedure result in controller but the procedure executes

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using the procedure shown here to get age counts

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetVotersByAge]   
    @lokSabhaID bigint = null, 
    @vidhanSabhaID bigint = null,
    @wardID bigint = null,  
    @year int     
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@vidhanSabhaID IS NULL AND @wardID IS NULL)     
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(voterID) AS 'Age Between 18 and 30' 
        FROM voterList          
        WHERE (@year - (datepart(year, dateOfBirth))) BETWEEN 18 AND 30 
          AND lokSabhaConstituencyID = @lokSabhaID  

        SELECT COUNT(voterID) AS 'Age Between 30 and 50' 
        FROM voterList          
        WHERE (@year - (datepart(year, dateOfBirth))) BETWEEN 30 AND 50 
          AND lokSabhaConstituencyID = @lokSabhaID

        SELECT COUNT(voterID) AS 'Age Above 50' 
        FROM voterList          
        WHERE (@year - (datepart(year, dateOfBirth))) > 50 
          AND lokSabhaConstituencyID = @lokSabhaID

        IF (@lokSabhaID IS NULL AND @wardID IS NULL)    
        BEGIN
            EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[sp_GetVotersByAge]  
                                        @lokSabhaID = 1,
                                        @vidhanSabhaID = NULL,      
                                        @wardID = NULL,         
                                        @year = 2000
```

Below is my controller method to call the stored procedure.

The Null values were set using

```
 var vidhanSabhaID_ = new SqlParameter("@vidhanSabhaID", SqlString.Null); 

var result = uow.getAgeReport_.SQLQuery<sp_GetVotersByAge_Result>("sp_GetVotersByAge @lokSabhaID, @vidhanSabhaID, @wardID, @year", lokSabhaID_,
 vidhanSabhaID_, wardID_, year_).FirstOrDefault();
```

My model is:

```
public class sp_GetVotersByAge_Result
{
         public int AgeBetween18and30 { get; set; }
         public int AgeBetween30and50 { get; set; }
         public int AgeMoreThan50 { get; set; }
}
```

The procedure works when I execute it in SQL Server. But I don't get any result when I execute it in Entity Framework

Comment: _"I dont get any result"_ - that's impossible. Do you get an empty result set? Or an exception? If the former, are you talking to the same database as you use in SSMS?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes , the result set is empty. and using the same values when I execute it in sqlserver , I get a non-empty result

Comment: Did you read the second part of my comment? Make sure you're talking to the same database.

Comment: Where do you set lokSabhaId_,, wardId_ and year? Also try setting vidhanSabhaId_ as SqlInt64.Null.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes ,I am talking to the same database . The entity framework executes the query with an empty result set

Comment: You do understand we can't repro this? There are, off the top of my head, two possible causes for the query in code returning different results than the same query in SSMS: either you're connecting to another database (or even server), or you're passing different values. You're the one who's going to have to do that troubleshooting, not much we can do from here.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I've set them too as null as I've written in the question .
well trying by sqlint64.null

Comment: And _year as SqlInt32, perhaps setting them as correct type would work.

Comment: Anyway your columns don't match your entity class, try using `[Column("Age Above 50")]` and such.

Comment: Perhaps you can also try calling the stored procedure without adding the parameters, if they are the same value as default.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've now changed the model class names matching with the procedure return. No Success up til yet